# Blackscreen while reboot with Ubu 15.04 after current Kernel update

Tags: graphics

I've got an Asus Notebook with I7 and GTX970. It's an dual boot EFI installation with secure-boot enabled, Win8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04.

Last Kernel Update (or maybe the 2nd last, i cannot verify it) causes a black screen after reboot. This happens also when rebooting Win8.1. But only after doing this current update.

I can reproduce it. Before the update, everything works fine.

I will test with the new 15.10 beta 2 to see, if it has the same bug.

Any ideas how to fix it at 15.04?

thx. in advance!

steve

Comment: which driver do you use for your GPU? Proprietary or comes bundle with kernel?